# Kapacitor record stream with influxdb connection probleme

Tags: windows, influxdb, telegraf, kapacitor

I'am trying to record a stream task in kapacitor & Influxdb.

I Use Windows 7 Entreprise, I've installed telegraf (to collect data) & influxdb and they both work (tested with grafana dashboard), but when i start Kapacitor and try to record a task, i get this error  "wsarecv : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" (And Kapacitor server Stop).

And I get this error on Kapacitor Server Cmd :

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x48 pc=0x5ada1d]

goroutine 46 [running]:
panic(0x1d23000, 0xc04200e070)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1af
github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/services/replay.(*Service).doRecordStream(0xc042
17d290, 0xc042ac5bc0, 0x24, 0x0, 0x0, 0xed1baf5dd, 0xc0079d8620, 0x2ed2e20, 0xc0
42679000, 0x1, ...)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/services/replay/service.go:
1256 +0x11d
github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/services/replay.(*Service).handleRecordStream.fu
nc1(0xc04202a680, 0xc04217d290, 0xc0425308c0, 0xc042531680, 0xc042ac5bc0, 0x24,
0xc04220e7e0, 0x62, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/services/replay/service.go:
622 +0x12c
created by github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/services/replay.(*Service).handleReco
rdStream
        /root/go/src/github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/services/replay/service.go:
624 +0x4f0

c:\InfluxDb\kapacitor>
```

Anyone got an idea on how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the latest release 1.4.0. See for the specific fix https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/pull/15422

The 1.4.0 release contains that fix. Version 1.4.0 was released 3 days ago and the downloads page should be updated soon.